# Hi how to use the lua script in order to toggle macro on and off

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

```
function OnEvent(event, arg, family)

if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 5 and family == "mouse") then

PlayMacro("Lustre Rotation")

end

if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED" and arg == 5 and family == "mouse") then

AbortMacro()

end

end
```

Hi I've been using the lua script (on Logitech G Hub) above in order to stop the macro as soon as I release the mouse button, but I don't wanna hold mouse button, instead I want to use the mouse button to toggle the macro. Please guide me through the script how to change to toggle on/off macro with mouse button. Thank you!

Comment: Actually, you don't need a Lua script for this.  When creating a new macro in GHUB, on the "select a type of macro you want to create" page choose "Toggle"

Answer (score 0):

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)

    if event == "G_PRESSED" and arg == 1 then
        AutoToggle = not AutoToggle
        if AutoToggle then
           PlayMacro("Lustre Rotation")
        else
          AbortMacro() 

    end

end
```

Comment: Consider adding more xplanation to help us understand more